# "No gpg key set matching launchpad one found" when uploading app using Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

I`m trying to upload my app using quickly, but usually getting this error:

> No gpg key set matching launchpad one found

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your OpenGPG key to launchpad, and your SSH key as well as your public key.

SSH: https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair

OpenGPG: 
https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey

Hopefully that should help :D

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, but.... now I can`t packagin my app , I got this error :

Comment: pavel@ubuntu:~/appmanager$ quickly package
.........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
............An error has occurred during package building
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting

Comment: I have no idea what to do , now.......

Comment: Have you tried "quickly share" or "quickly release"?

Comment: If either of those don't work, try "quickly package --extras" to see if it builds on your machine.

Comment: You might want to try this to troubleshoot the packaging failure: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu