# Why do I have a gnomekeyring.IOError when doing "quickly share"?

Tags: application-development, quickly, launchpad, gnome-keyring

When I want to push my app to Launchpad by doing `quickly share --verbose`, I get the following Gnome Keyring error:

```
Get Launchpad Settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 101, in <module>
    launchpad = launchpadaccess.initialize_lpi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/launchpadaccess.py", line 91, in initialize_lpi
    allow_access_levels=["WRITE_PRIVATE"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 539, in login_with
    credential_save_failed, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 342, in _authorize_token_and_login
    authorization_engine.unique_consumer_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/credentials.py", line 282, in load
    return self.do_load(unique_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/credentials.py", line 336, in do_load
    'launchpadlib', unique_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 34, in get_password
    return _keyring_backend.get_password(service_name, username)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 154, in get_password
    items = gnomekeyring.find_network_password_sync(username, service)
gnomekeyring.IOError
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

This used to work, so this means that I already have SSH and GPG configured. This is probably part of the explanation: I have this error when I am connected to this machine through a ssh tunnel with X forwarding. But I don't have it when I have physical access to the computer.

Could you please give me some indications on what to do?

Comment: It's a very interesting question, because I don't see why Quickly should call gnome-keyring except for the GPG auth when signing the deb source package. Given the deadline, you may wnat to try the `ubuntu-app-devel` IRC channel; I believe some of the quickly devs hang out there.

Comment: Could you give us some more info? Do you have both your SSH and GPG keys set up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/160782/no-gpg-key-set-matching-launchpad-one-found-when-uploading-app-using-quickly

Comment: Thank you. I added some info at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because launchpadlib (the client side library for accessing launchpad) stores its credentials in the gnome keyring. quickly uses launchpadlib to access Launchpad.

See also this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-keyring/+bug/796873

The best workaround for this is to make sure you are running inside of an environment where the GNOME keyring is available.